# Why might singular functions be important in the study of the Fractional Quantum Hall Effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, mathematics

In studying a course on Quantum Mechanics, I was led to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_function), which explains that a *singular function* is one which is only non-differentiable on a measure zero subset of $\mathbb{R}$, at all points where it is differentiable it has derivative zero and yet it is non-constant! This is a very interesting property from a mathematical perspective but unlikely to have a physical meaning (or so I thought!).

However, on reading the Wikipedia page it says that indeed singular functions in the sense above *do* have relevance in Quantum Mechanics and in some way relate to the *fractional Quantum Hall effect*. I am actually studying for a Mathematics degree and so find the idea of Measure Theory appearing in even a minor sense in serious physics very intriguing! Anything similar to the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) having physical relevance sounds fascinating...

Unfortunately, the page gives no references for this claim and I could not find any references online discussing where singular functions come up.

**Could somebody give an example of such singular functions coming up in the study of the *fractional quantum hall effect* as mentioned above? Preferably any answer will come with a basic explanation of the investigations that led to these functions arising and any physical significance to the functions being singular.**

Comment: @mmesser314: I know and I link to that exact page in my question. In fact, my entire question is based on the definition you link to.

Comment: Singular functions like e.g. $1/r^2$, $\delta(x)$, etc., pop up all over physics.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Did you read the question? Neither of those examples you gave are examples of singular functions in the sense discussed above, i.e. neither of them are differentiable on all but a measure zero subset of the reals and have derivative zero at all points where they are differentiable yet are not constant. I link to a Wikipedia page in the answer where singular functions in the sense I just mentioned are discussed. The question is very specific - in what sense could I make the question more precise?

Comment: @Qmechanic: I have also removed the tag of "singularities" as, if you read the question, that is *not* the sense of singular function we discussing here.

Comment: As a general rule, questions of the form "what are examples of X in physics?" tend to be considered too broad and not a good fit for the site, even if "X" is a very interesting topic. I see that you have edited the question to include a specific request for the FQHE at the end, but focusing both the title and question body on that example would likely be helpful.

Comment: @J.Murray: I will do exactly as you suggest as I am incredibly invested in having this question answered, however I really suggest considering how rare what I'm describing it is. I understand that my question is open, in that it allowed people to list potentially examples from all across physics, but the property I'm looking for (singularity as defined above) is incredibly rare in mathematics and I would be surprised for it to even appear once in physics.

Comment: @J.Murray: Continuing the previous comment, please consider that previous commenters have seemed to think the functions I'm looking for are very common because "singular functions" are being confused with "functions with a singularity" such as 1/x etc. As discussed in the question, I am *not* discussing those functions but instead looking at a bizarre property of a function which I didn't expect to have any physical significance (definition given above). Thus I suspect that even in its original form, my question was very narrow and I doubt it would have been easy to find even one example.

Comment: Yes, I know. Again, your question is interesting; however, the general policy on PSE is that questions which broadly seek examples of some mathematical structure being employed in physics tend to be considered "list-like." There are [debates and differing opinions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/good-list-bad-list) about when such questions should be closed, but the fact of the matter is that a specific question about an example of a mathematical structure will essentially always be a better fit for PSE than a blanket request for examples.

Comment: I spent several years studying the FQHE and never came across this particular notion of "singular functions." If singular functions are at the center of the FQHE, they must be buried very deeply there.

Comment: @J.Murray: Given how rare the property is that we are discussing, would it seem reasonable to make the question more general if I am unable to find examples of singular functions in the study of FQHE? Given that I am interested in finding examples of such functions, should I instead ask separate questions over time asking for examples of these functions in different, but specific, areas of physics?

Comment: @Qmechanic: because in the link to the Wikipedia page given in the question it is claimed that there are functions with the same famous properties as the Cantor function which appear in models explaining FQHE: functions which are differentiable on all but a measure zero subset of their domain which have derivative zero wherever it is defined and are continuous and yet nonconstant. The Cantor function is simply the most commonly known example of such a function and I asked the question because I indeed find it remarkable that anything similar would appear in physics.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I have left the tag ``resource recommendations`` off the question as you suggested but have removed the tag ``singularities`` as it is not relevant to this question, given this is not the definition of singular function used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a comment, but I am posting it as an answer since comments don't display pictures.

When I saw the circle map plot in your first Wikipedia link, and given that you are asking about the FQHE, my mind immediately went to this very well-known plot of the Hall resistance showing various FQH plateaus:
[image]

While this does have the characteristic "staircase" shape, it's obviously not a singular function in the sense you're asking about, so I dismissed this idea pretty quickly.

However, after going back and looking at the plot of the Cantor function, it again reminded me very much of the staircase plot of $R_H$. So much so that I started to be convinced that this is the sense in which the Wikipedia author suggests singular functions appear in the FQHE.

As I said, the Hall resistance cannot literally be a singular function. For this we would need (at least!) for there to be a FQHE state for every rational filling fraction, which is not the case. But I wonder if the Wikipedia author meant to give a non-example which is merely evocative of other examples of singular functions, rather than providing an actual example.

Comment: +1 Thanks! You might be unfortunately correct about this (especially given that you appear to be an expert in the field!) but I will leave the question open for a little longer in the hope that we might find an actual singular function (especially given how much effort I had to put in to get this question going :)). Secretly, of course, if the moderators allowed it I would be interested in hearing about their potential appearances in other areas of physics mentioned in the Wiki page like the ANNNI model and Frenkel-Kontorova...

Comment: I'm not really familiar with those models, but I found this review of the ANNNI model that includes a "devil's staircase" plot in Fig. 13: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157388901408?via%3Dihub It seems that this plot is coming from soliton solutions of the sine-Gordon equation, which also shows up when studying the Frekel-Kontorova.

Comment: That's brilliant!! I actually had completely given up hope to be honest but I'm very very pleasesd with this result - it does appear the graph and discussion is about a genuine singular function (though the discussion appears upon a first cursory glance to be suggesting this is a faulty prediction?). I'll accept your answer, thank you very much.

Comment: Of course you have no obligation to help further (or really at all!) but yeah if you learn anything more about this or other examples, just know I'll always be eager to listen.